# Remove zeros, if any, from a certain part of a serial number

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a lot of products with serial numbers that are formatted as follows:

```
L12345-001-1
L12346-095-1
L44543-365-0
```

I need to run a query that removes all the zero placeholders for the item number between the dashes "-". So a correct query would change the values above to this:

```
L12345-1-1
L12346-95-1
L44543-365-0
```

I have spent no time learning regex and need a quick fix like yesterday. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MySQL 5.7 you can use the following solution using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', 1), CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED), SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', -1)) 
FROM products
```

To `UPDATE` the values on database you can use the following solution:

```
UPDATE products 
  SET snumber = CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', 1), CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', 2), '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED), SUBSTRING_INDEX(snumber, '-', -1))
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72276de8d5bc19e5075d78aba821fc4c)

---

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use regular expressions to solve this, using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) and [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(snumber, '-.*-', CONCAT('-', CAST(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(snumber, '-.*-'), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED), '-')) 
FROM products
```

To `UPDATE` the values on database you can use the following solution:

```
UPDATE products
  SET snumber = REGEXP_REPLACE(snumber, '-.*-', CONCAT('-', CAST(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(snumber, '-.*-'), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED), '-'))
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a38065bb775192bbb1f4a84d8b80f733)

Answer (score 2):

REGEX is on my todo list too, You could use plain old substring with cast

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id varchar(20));
insert into t values
('L12345-001-1'),
('L12346-095-1'),
('L44543-365-0');


select id,
         concat(substring_index(id,'-',1),
         '-',
         cast(substring_index(substring_index(id,'-',2),'-',-1) as unsigned),
         '-',
         substring_index(id,'-',-1) 
         ) fixed
from T
;

+--------------+--------------+
| id           | fixed        |
+--------------+--------------+
| L12345-001-1 | L12345-1-1   |
| L12346-095-1 | L12346-95-1  |
| L44543-365-0 | L44543-365-0 |
+--------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This looks good and close to what I almost had. Now to turn that select into an update of those rows? Thank you Salmon for taking the time to work on this.